# XAML, similar to float in HTML?

Tags: xaml, layout, css-float

Image and Text, "float" and "clear" in HTML, gives possibility to build Text flow. How to do this in XAML? With a sample if possible.

Comment: Interesting problem to solve in XAML, look forward to answers and will try to think of one myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do text flow in XAML is to use the FlowDocument control.

Here's and [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/22/wpf-text-reading-and-flow-document-support-and-the-new-nytimes-daily-mail-and-seattle-post-intelligencer-reader-applications.aspx) from ScottGu, you can also google for many more.